# Android Calendar illegalArgumentException

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following error message

illegalArgumentException: Only sync adapters may write to ownerAccount
when using

```
**this line:---** values.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.OwnerAccount, 
AccountOwner);
values.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.AccountName, AccountName);
values.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.Id, CalendarID);
values.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.Visible, 1);
values.Put(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.SyncEvents, 1);
cr.Insert(CalendarContract.Calendars.ContentUri, values);
```

How is this possible tried every example.
I get the account name from the AccountPicker in my OnActivityResult like

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);   

    if(requestCode == MyClass.RequestCode && resultCode == Result.Ok)
    {
        GSDEvents.AccountName = data.GetStringExtra(AccountManager.KeyAccountName);
        DependencyService.Get<MyClass>().AddCalendar(8, GSDFuncties.ApplicationName, MyClass.AccountName, MyClass.AccountName);
        Toast.MakeText(this, GSDEvents.AccountName, ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }


}
```

Comment: Do you have the proper manifest permissions to R/W : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>

Comment: Yes read and Write of the calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved by using:**

```
 calUri = calUri.BuildUpon()
    .AppendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CallerIsSyncadapter, "true")
    .AppendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.AccountName, AccountName)
    .AppendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.InterfaceConsts.AccountType, CalendarContract.AccountTypeLocal)
    .Build();

cr.Insert(calUri, values);
```